# How to change the default which columns are shown in Finder, but *only* when I switch to list view?

Tags: finder

I think I don't need the "Kind" column in list view in Finder.
I know I can disable that column by ctrl-clicking on the header and deselecting it.

What I would like to have is the "Kind" column disabled by default, but I don't want list view as the default view in Finder.

Is that possible? Maybe using a Terminal command?
(I have googled , but could not find a solution. Only stuff about column widths, with which I am not concerned here.)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From Finder - View Menu > Show View Options or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>

Uncheck 'Kind' & optionally 'Always open in' then click Use as Defaults.
Note this will only affect windows that don't already have a pref set.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  Doesn't that make list view the default for all folders? (at least those, that don't have a preference set yet?)

Comment: It would, hence the word 'optionally'.